# DataSchemaError: database 'db_a' not found

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I created a tenant, then created a database in the tenant, then created a table and wrote data as follow:

```
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

the first was succeed, but when I repeat the process again,

```
DROP TENANT IF EXISTS tenant_a;
DROP USER IF EXISTS user_a;
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
CREATE DATABASE db_a;
\c db_a
CREATE TABLE air_a (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air_a (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);
```

the result as flollow:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"020004","error_message":"DataSchemaError: database 'db_a' not found"}
```

why the database was not found?